# Nginx: deny requests based on certain conditions

Tags: nginx

In Apache I have a bunch of rules to block certain unwanted requests.

```
# Block libwww-perl/5.805 from attempting to exploit security vulnerabilities  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^libwww\-perl/.+ [NC]     
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule . - [F,L] 

# Block generic Java-based clients
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Java/1\.6\.0_04 [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F,L]

# Block generic Mozilla clients
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/5\.0$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish the same task in nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Block libwww-perl/5.805 from attempting to exploit security vulnerabilities
if ($http_user_agent ~* ^libwww\-perl/.+) {
    if ($query_string ~ \.) {
        return 403;
    }
}

# Block generic Java-based clients
if ($http_user_agent ~* ^Java/1\.6\.0_04) {
    return 403;
}

# Block generic Mozilla clients
if ($http_user_agent ~* ^Mozilla/5\.0$) {
    return 403;
}
```

`~` is a case-sensitive match, `~*` is case-insensitive, & `!~` & `!~*` are their negations.

Unfortunately neither `&&` nor `||` are valid in nginx if statements, so nesting is the way to go.

Comment: I don't know if nginx can support nested `if` statements. So note workarounds like this http://www.rosslawley.co.uk/2010/01/nginx-how-to-multiple-if-statements.html

Comment: Nginx doesn't support nested statement. +1 for the answer.